# Prove $\lim_{n\to\infty} (X_{n}) = \lim_{n\to\infty} (Y_{n})$ implies that $\lim_{n\to\infty} E[X_{n}] = \lim_{n\to\infty} E[Y_{n}]$

Tags: limits, probability-theory

Prove $\lim_{n\to\infty} (X_{n}) = \lim_{n\to\infty} (Y_{n})$ implies that $\lim_{n\to\infty} E[X_{n}] = \lim_{n\to\infty} E[Y_{n}]$, given $X_{n}, Y_{n}$ are increasing sequences of positive integrable random variables on a probability space.

**The Set Up**

I am self-teaching probability theory, and I am reading a book on the subject, specifically "Probability Theory in Finance" by Sean Dineen (bottom of page 126, if anyone has it).

I have hit a brick wall with part of the proof of the above claim.

The claim is (fairly) easily provable for $X_{n}, Y_{n}$ bounded. So here I am just considering the unbounded case, i.e. $\lim_{n\to\infty} (X_{n}) = \lim_{n\to\infty} (Y_{n}) = \infty$

Considering just $X_{n}$ first (and now I am just writing what is written in the book), since the $X_{n}$ are integrable, we can find an increasing sequence $(j_{n})$ such that

$E[X_{n}] - E[X_{n}^{[j_{n}]}] < 1/2^{n}$

where

$X_{n}^{[j_{n}]} = X_{n}$ if $X_{n} < j_{n}$, and $X_{n}^{[j_{n}]} = j_{n}$ otherwise (i.e. a censoring of the random variable, which is bounded).

This makes sense to me as we define $Lim_{m->\infty} E[X_{n}^{[m]}] = E[
X_{n}] < \infty$, since the $X_{n}$ are integrable. Hence I can always find such a sequence that "brings $E[X_{n}^{[j_{n}]}]$ closer and closer to $E[X_{n}]$", and arbitrarily 'closer'.

**My Problem**

Now, the author then claims that, for all $n$, we either have:

$X_{n}(\omega) - X_{n}^{[j_{n}]}(\omega) \leq 1/2^{j_n} $, or $X_{n}^{[j_{n}]}(\omega) = j_{n}$.

And then asserts that this implies that

$lim_{n->\infty}X_{n}^{[j_{n}]} = lim_{n->\infty}X_{n} $, since $j_{n} \geq n$ (?!)

I cannot fathom where these final two claims/assertions are derived from and really need some help?!
Intuitively I can kind of 'see' why the two limits are equal, given their expectations are equal, but mathematically I cannot understand why the above is fact.

Once I can be comfortable with this, then I can proceed, as I have converted the problem of unboundedness into one of boundedness, and I 'know' how to tacklet that.

Appreciate this is half out of context, so if there is anything else I can do to make clearer, please let me know.

Thanks for any assistance at all.

Comment: Do you know Monotone Convergence Theorem? The result is immediate from that theorem: $\lim EX_n=E\lim X_n=E\lim Y_n=\lim EY_n$.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes, I am aware of this theorem. The above result is on the path towards proving that very theorem. So i'm afraid I can't (if i'm following the book as I am) assume the Monotone Convergence Theorem until I have proved the above!